# Packaging Font with WPF application

Tags: wpf, fonts, licensing

I want to package Microsoft Reader's - Frutiger font with my application as a resource. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx) says:

> As with most types of software, font files are licensed, rather than
>   sold. Licenses that govern the use of fonts vary from vendor to vendor
>   but in general most licenses, including those covering the fonts
>   Microsoft supplies with applications and Windows, do not allow the
>   fonts to be embedded within applications or otherwise redistributed.
>   Therefore, as a developer it is your responsibility to ensure that you
>   have the required license rights for any font you embed within an
>   application or otherwise redistribute.

It also talks about `fsType` flag that indicates font embedding licensing rights. I am not quite sure how to figure that out, can I use this `Font` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware the licence for this font prohibits it from being reused.  if you view the file details for the font it states:

> This font may not be given away, sold, rented or loaned to others in any way.

It also goes on to discuss acquiring licences for the fonts.  If you go here you can see the purchase options for the Frutiger font:

http://www.linotype.com/469/frutiger-family.html

Comment: Is there a list of wpf redistibutable font available anywhere so that I can pick one. I dont want to spam SO with question on every font I have picked:)

Comment: I am not sure on a list of fonts (I tend to use windows fonts so I know they are available).  If you open the Windows\Fonts folder you can right-click and see properties on individual fonts which includes licence details in the details tab.  I am sure you could Google for redistributable fonts and get quite a few hits though.