# How to pick WPF application Font thats always available on target machine?

Tags: wpf, fonts, installation

In continuation with the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746869/packaging-font-with-wpf-application) I asked, I want to know the list of `Font` I can use in my WPF application so that in the target machine (Windows XP) it won't fall back to any default.

- I don't think I can use anything that comes up in the xaml intellisense ?
- Can I get this list from somewhere or should I look into licensing info of every font I am trying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/) that gives me the fonts installed with specific products, in my case [XP](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=135).